# Whatsapp Web QR Code flashes and vanishes

Tags: help, browsers

I am using Tor browser 7.5.6 (latest, 32 bits) on windows 10. I like to use Whatsapp on web. So I go to : 
https://web.whatsapp.com/

The site shows a QR code which I scan with my phone. And boom! I can access Whatsapp on my desktop via tor.

Now the problem is, for past 2 days, the QR code flashes for a while and then replaced by a timeout image. I googled and found one possible solution. That is disabling hardware acceleration. But I have intel-integrated-graphics, for which that option is not available. :-(

However, my Firefox 61.0.1 (64 bits) works absolutely fine with Whatsapp-web.

Can someone please throw more light on the situation ?

Thank you!

-Gamma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the adress bar in Tor enter: about:config
2. Accept the risk
3. Search for privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts
4. Change the value from "true" to "false"
5. Open WhatsApp web and if you are prompted to authorize the Input Canvas simply accept.
6. Refresh the page
7. Enjoy WhatsApp Web

Answer (score 2):

Enter `about:config` into the address bar. You'll see a warning. Please be careful when making changes. Enter `privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts` into the search bar and double-click the entry. It should be set to `false` now. The setting was immediately changed and you can close the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I acted differently.
I inspected the code with the browser and changed the css code that hide the qr-code:

```
display: block;
```